# SSL from cloudflare not working?

Tags: nginx, ssl

So I follow this guide [here](https://odinsql.com/2014/12/free-ssl-with-cloudflare-openssl-and-nginx-on-ubuntu/) to setup my cloudflare and to automatically forward http > https, but I am getting "SSL handshake failed". If anyone can help me solve this issue that would 100% appreciated!

My current configuration for my nginx is this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name subdomain.domain.pw;
    return 301 https://subdomain.domain.pw$request_uri; 
}

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name subdomain.domain.pw;
    return 301 https://subdomain.domain.pw$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/subdomain.domain.pw.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/subdomain.domain.pw.error.log error;

    root /var/www/subdomain.domain.pw;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;

    server_name subdomain.domain.pw;

    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    #ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    #ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
}
```

[EDIT] Fixed by removing the unneeded server block. Thanks to @SledgeHammer

Comment: Might not solve your problem, but you should delete the middle server block. I'm talking about `server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name subdomain.domain.pw;
    return 301 https://subdomain.domain.pw$request_uri;
}`. Also what are your CloudFlare settings in the Crypto section for that domain?

Comment: @SledgeHammer Well removing the un-needed block fixed my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: This block is not needed because you're using it on a subdomain, but if you decide to use this for your main domain, you might need it because in the tutorial it was being used to redirect the www subdomain to the main one.

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to delete the middle virtualhost:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name subdomain.domain.pw;
    return 301 https://subdomain.domain.pw$request_uri;
}
```

The next step would be to alter your SSL VirtualHost so it uses [CloudFlare's cipher suite](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200933580-What-cipher-suites-does-CloudFlare-use-for-SSL-), add this into the body of the last VirtualHost (replacing the existing ssl_protocols, ssl_ciphers and ssl_prefer_server_ciphers config variables):

```
ssl_protocols               TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers                 EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
```

Comment: As I already said I fixed it.

Comment: The answer is there not just for your benefit, but for others who come here later.